# Bootstrap 5 offcanvas error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-table, off-canvas-menu

Looping through a list to create a table of information and offcanvas menus to display additional information when a table row `<tr>` is clicked. Currently, I receive the "parentNode" error when I click on any . Any ideas why I get this error?

The `<tr>` has a "data-bs-target" point towards the correct "id" for the Offcanvas but for some reason it does not know the parentNode.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr4Wg.png)

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-sm" id="t1">
  <thead class="table-secondary">
    <th scope="col" class="name">
      Host Name
    </th>
    <th scope="col" class="ip_address">
      IP Address
    </th>

         ... 

  </thead>
  <tbody class="lan-table">
    {% for host in hosts %}

      <tr class="host-row" data-view='host' data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#{{host.fqdn}}-host-details">
        <td class="host-fqdn"></td>
        <td class="host-ip-address"></td>

           ...

      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>

...

{% for host in hosts %}
  <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end w-25" data-bs-scroll="true" tabindex="-1" id="{{host.fqdn}}-host-details" style="min-width: 400px;">

    ...

  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Below is a screenshot capturing the page being generated correctly. Note: Since this is capturing fqdn information, I blocked my domain for security.
[Static HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFAJw.png)

Comment: Could you please add some code so we can see what are you doing?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I've added some of the code to give the basic structure.

Comment: Maybe you are modifying your host.fqdn variable? Can you inspect the static generated page and see if ids are correct? I don't think so, but I don't really find any errors on your html. I suppouse you are importing correctly both bootstrap css and js

Comment: Yes, the static page is being generated with all the ids correct. And I assume my css and js are importing correctly because this is the only time I have an issue with my page. I've added a screenshot to show.

Comment: The only thing left that comes to my mind is that maybe offcanvas does not support to be toggled through a table row... maybe? Try to change it to a list, but I'm kinda lost on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out why my offcanvas was not working. My "data-bs-target" ids had period characters in them and the javascript for offcanvas uses querySelector which requires escaping the special characters to work.

Here is a link mentioning it. [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Notes)